# Unable to open S3 zip file downloaded using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

My `AWS S3` contains some files and I want to download those files through my application as a zip file. I'm able to download the zip file successfully but while the file I'm getting an error `Unexpected end of archive` and also the CSV file size is 0 inside the zip.

I did dig a lot but not able to understand the exact solutions.

Here's the code:

```java
String zipFileName = "MyZipFile.zip";

String fileName = "test.csv";

filePath = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(filePath));
System.out.println("file:" + filePath);

// get file from S3
S3Object s3Obj = awsClient.downloadFile(filePath);

byte[] s3Bytes = s3Obj.getObjectContent().readAllBytes();

// create zip
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(s3Bytes.length);
ZipOutputStream zipOutStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrOutputStream);
ZipEntry zip = new ZipEntry(fileName);
zipOutStream.putNextEntry(zip);
zipOutStream.write(s3Bytes, 0, s3Bytes.length);
byte[] streamBytes = byteArrOutputStream.toByteArray();

// close streams
zipOutStream.closeEntry();
zipOutStream.close();
closeQuietly(byteArrOutputStream);

// prepare download
System.out.println("streamBytes:" + streamBytes + " len:" + streamBytes.length);
System.out.println("s3Bytes:" + s3Bytes + " len:" + s3Bytes.length);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
headers.setContentLength(streamBytes.length);
headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", zipFileName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should close your zip output stream to have everything written to the underlying byte array stream *before* you extract the byte array... Ie reorder the lines to:

```
// close streams
zipOutStream.closeEntry();
zipOutStream.close();
byte[] streamBytes = byteArrOutputStream.toByteArray();
closeQuietly(byteArrOutputStream);
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this mattered?

Comment: The zip stream has its own buffer, which is flushed to the next stream when you close it. Not until after that the data is available in the byte array output stream.

Comment: `zipOutStream.closeEntry();` is not needed when there is a `zipOutStream.close();` right after it. Further, if `closeQuietly(byteArrOutputStream);` does what the name suggests, it’s obsolete as well, as `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn’t need to be closed (and if it did, the close operation was again misplaced, being after the `toByteArray()` call). And `zipOutStream.close()` did already call `close()` on the underlying `ByteArrayOutputStream` anyway…